# Use current date in github actions inputs

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

Is there a way to set the current date as a default value for workflow_dispatch input?

```
name: Code Build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      releaseVersion:
        description: "the release version of the build"
        type: string
        default: HERE SHOULD BE CURRENT DATE
        required: true
```

Comment: I would make it optional and then use a separate run step to set the date if the value is empty.,

Comment: Same here as Benjamin: you cannot create any calculations for the default, only predefined options like for example in an Option Picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, it's not possible to calculate the default value of the input on each workflow run.

I would recommend using the [Current date time](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/current-date-time) GH Action (for example) and the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Current Date Demo

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      releaseVersion:
        description: "the release version of the build"
        type: string
        default: ''
        required: false # Not required

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get current date
        if: inputs.releaseVersion == ''
        id: date
        uses: Kaven-Universe/github-action-current-date-time@v1
        with:
          format: "YYYY-MM-DD"

      - name: Test
        run: |
          echo "${{ inputs.releaseVersion || steps.date.outputs.time }}"
```

Example of the Workflow output when the input wasn't specified:
[image: screenshot].